# How to get GeoJSON data of Neighborhoods / Quartier of Morocco County?

Tags: python, json, database, geojson

I am looking for suggestions on APIs or GitHub repositories that could help me solve this problem efficiently. Ideally, I need a solution that provides reliable and up-to-date data for Morocco's neighborhoods and allows me to easily integrate it into my project.